# Кнопка изображение с текстом внизу

Tags: android, xml

Как мне добавить текст под изображение чтобы при нажатии выделялся и текст и изображение вместе и переходило в мой фрагмент? Что надо добавить? Есть кнопка, а как добавить текст я ни знаю подскажите кто-нибудь.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imv_SettingHomeMain"
            android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например можно использовать обычную кнопку с картинкой вверху:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/home_btn_test"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_settings"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
android:paddingTop="32sp"
android:drawablePadding="-15sp"
android:text="Settings"/>
```

Так же есть виджет - ImageButton но он вам вероятнее всего не подойдет, так как вы в него можете установить только картинку. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton) есть подобный вопрос про кнопки.